# access an integer and string globally in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

i want to access a integer and a string from a class to all the other classes?
what is the best way to do it?
i want to increase the values any where in the program and then want to update them in the class declared....

any idea how to achieve this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a question (and good answers) about [singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).

You could also use the app delegate, as frankodwyer suggested, and access it from anywhere using:

```
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

For ease of use and type safety I use a category like this:

```
// put his in your delegate header file
@interface UIApplication(MyAppAdditions)
+ (MyAppDelegate*)sharedDelegate;
@end

// put his in your delegate implementation file
@implementation UIApplication(MyAppAdditions)
+ (MyAppDelegate*)sharedDelegate {
    return (MyAppDelegate*)[[self sharedApplication] delegate];
}
@end
```

Now you can access your app delegate from everywhere: `[UIApplication sharedDelegate]`

Comment: +1 nice - I didn't know there was a shortcut to get the delegate like that. I've been manually setting it as a property of views..doh!

Comment: I like to do something similar, but with #define's instead, like so:
#define UIApp [UIApplication sharedApplication]
#define UIAppDelegate ((MyAppDelegate*)[UIApp delegate])

Comment: is there any other way?
means i have one uitable which has 2 section.both section contains multiple rows.both section refers to two different views.i want to increment a integer in both views.and when i return back from table i want to update in database

Comment: please post your code in more details.... and what if i do not want to use appdelegate. how to create global variables in other class and access them without creating class's instance

Answer (score 2):

You could make the integer and string properties of your app delegate and pass references to the delegate around to your views. I do something like this myself, though to be honest it is a pain and also a little error prone to make the app delegate available to all the views.

Or (and this is probably better), you could declare a singleton class (google the singleton pattern) as one of your data classes, and have your integer/string be properties of that. Then you could access the getters/setters of your singleton from anywhere in your program. You will need to take extra care if you have multiple threads however,